# Diagonal photo fade in Python

Tags: python, transparency, photo, fade

I am looking to create a diagonal fade on a photo in python.

I am able to create a vertical and horizontal fade, but when put together one overwrites the other. I know why, I just can't figure out how to fix it. I realize there are probably a lot of things in here that don't make sense, relatively new to Python and just trying to figure it out. Thanks in advance!

```
img = Image.open('Anacapa 011.tif')

img = img.copy()
img.putalpha(150)

width, height = img.size
pixels = img.load()

for y in range (int(0), int(height)):
    alpha = 150 - int((height*.50 - y)/height/.3 * 150)
    for x in range(width):
        pixels[x, y] = pixels[x, y][:3] + (alpha,)
for y in range(y, height):
    for x in range(width):
        pixels[x, y] = pixels[x, y][:3] + (0,)

img1 = img.copy()

width1, height1 = img.size
pixels1 = img.load()

for x1 in range (int(0), int(width1)):
    alpha = 150 - int((x1 - width1*.4)/width1/.3 * 150)
    for y1 in range(height1):
        pixels1[x1, y1] = pixels1[x1, y1][:3] + (alpha,)
for x1 in range(x1, width1):
    for y1 in range(height1):
        pixels1[x1, y1] = pixels1[x1, y1][:3] + (0,)
```